# Distinguish between primary and secondary click

Tags: kotlin, compose-desktop

Working with composable in Kotlin.
I have TreeView with Items which are already clickable, but now I need to distinguish between primary and secondary clicks (mouse buttons), but mouseclickable is experimental, so need to check it in another way to open a contextmenu.
Any ideas?

Comment: experimental does not mean that you can't use it, it just means that you may need to update the use of this method with the new API in new versions of Compose. If you don't want to do that, you can copy the source code of the desired method and use it without any problems and without fear of API updates. I personally suppress all such warnings as updating API doesn't take much time in my projects, I don't think it may cause much problems unless your project is really huge

Comment: thx Pylyp Dukhov